# NetworkManager window won't go away

Tags: kde, networkmanager

Earlier today I was doing things that involved the Linux NetworkManager. At some point, what looks like the NetworkManager widget appeared in the middle of the screen and I can't get it to go away. It has none of the usual window decorations and no "X" in the upper right. It works--I can click on other buttons and stuff happens. It survives reboots and even complete shutdown/restarts. Killing NetworkManager with sudo killall -9 doesn't help--the list of connections just goes blank and is replaced with "No connections" and the comes back when I restart NetworkManager.

[image]

Any idea how I can get rid of this thing?

Fedora 33, KDE 5.20

Comment: try alt-F4 or ctrl-w  hotkeys

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling the widget:

On Fedora:

```
sudo dnf remove plasma-nm -y
```

On Debian/Ubuntu:

```
sudo apt uninstall plasma-nm
```

If this works (as it should), you can install it again

Comment: Yeah, probably would have worked, but Fedora dnf would also have removed another 25 dependent packages and that was just too scary.  I guess I'll just live with it until my next OS upgrade. Thanks for the suggestion.